# php/jquery comparing content fails not working correctly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, parsing

need to play sound on different content, but it's playing sound every time

only one echo in get.php work fine and if i change code in get.php to parser code it
act's like content is not the same all time

#

html body code

#

```
<div id="main"><?php include("ajax/get.php");?></div>
    <audio id="sound" src="sound/sound.ogg" controls type="audio/ogg" preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                var audio=document.getElementById("sound");
                setInterval(function()
                {
                    $.get('ajax/get.php',function(data){
                    if ($('#main').html() !== data){
                        $('#main').html(data);
                        audio.play();                   
                    }                   
                  });
                }, 5000);
        </script>
```

#

php parser code

#

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html=file_get_html('supersite-content');

    $ret = $html->find('.request');
    foreach ($ret as $key) {
    echo "$key</br></br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Browser modifies the html mostly on render time so it is not the same as in textual form. You can add a cache to compare the original string. Something like this:

```
var audio = $("#sound");
var lastDate = null;
setInterval(function()
{
    $.get('ajax/get.php', function(data) {
    if (lastDate !== data){
        lastDate = data;
        $('#main').html(data);
        audio.play();                   
    }                   
  });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: all ingenious is simple^^ big tnx!